# Как прицепить vertical Scroll View в Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, monotouch

Здравствуйте
Я новичок в программировании под iOS, использую Xamarin(C#). По примеру из сайта developer.xamarin.com создал горизонтальный Scroll View на который вешаются buttons вот код

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using Foundation;
using CoreGraphics;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{
    ScrollingButtonsController ();
}

UIScrollView scrollView;
List<UIButton> buttons;

public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //MyScrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
    //MyScrollView.contentSize= CGSizeMake(CGFloat.width, CGFloat.height);          

    //end
    nfloat h = 50.0f;
    nfloat w = 50.0f;
    nfloat padding = 10.0f;
    nint n = 100;

    scrollView = new UIScrollView {
        Frame = new CGRect (0, 100, View.Frame.Height, h + 2 * padding),
        ContentSize = new CGSize ((w + padding) * n, h),
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red,
        AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
    };

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        var button = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
        button.SetTitle (i.ToString (), UIControlState.Normal);
        button.Frame = new CGRect (padding * (i + 1) + (i * w), padding, w, h);
        scrollView.AddSubview (button);
        buttons.Add (button);
    }

    View.AddSubview (scrollView);

    //UIScrollView scrollView;
//scrollView = new UIScrollView (
//      new CGRect (0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height));
//  View.AddSubview (scrollView);



}
public void ScrollingButtonsController ()
{
    buttons = new List<UIButton> ();

}

public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
{
    base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}


}
}
```

Задача состоит в том чтобы сделать вертикальный скроллер на который будут вешаться Text Views и Images, позиции и размеры рисуются в Дизайнере Xamarin (Main.storyboard), там же пытался поставить Scroll View, но он почему то не работает.
Просьба помочь в решении этой задачи, как все это сделать правильно?
Много гуглил но ничего что решило мою задачу не нашел.

Заранее Спасибо.